# Excel crashes following ADO connection

Tags: excel, vb6, ado

I'm trying to query a large named range within Excel

The following connection works well but is very slow when the range contains thousands of rows. Moreover, it seems that there is a limit on the number of records.

```
    strCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                     "Data Source=" & strFile & ";" & _
                     "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;"""
```

I'm trying to use a different connection but then, VB6 crashes!

```
myRangeName = "namedRangeWorksheet"
xlapp.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersTo:=TrueUsedRange
'**********************************
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
strFile = oWB.FullName
Set strCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strCon.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source = " & strFile & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"

strSQL = "SELECT * from namedRangeWorksheet"    ''Named range
rs.Open strSQL, strCon, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 works well on my computer when applied to Access database

Comment: With *"crashes"* you mean Excel dies or just showing an error?

Comment: VB6 crashes (not Excel)!

Comment: Still confused: Are you talking about VB6 or VBA? And what do you mean with "crashes"? Do you get any meaningful error message? What exactly happens?

Comment: VB6! It crashes and closes without any message!

Comment: I removed the VBA tag, if you are using VB6 instead. The tags are used to alert people who are interested in them; using the wrong ones is unhelpful.